# How to validate if selected date (datepicker) is a future date?

Tags: javascript, date, input

I have a date picker where a user selects the date. If the date is prior to the current date, then an error message will display **"Please choose a future date."** If a future date is chosen, a success message displays. But, only the error message displays every time.

Is there something unique about the datepicker?

```js
function getDate() {
    var givenDate = document.myForm.inputDate.value;
  var todaysDate = new Date();
  if (givenDate >= todaysDate) {
    result.innerHTML = 'Great! You\'re starting on ' + givenDate;
    result.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "Please choose a future date.";
    result.style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="date" id="inputDate" name="inputDate" onchange="getDate()">
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.myForm.inputDate.value` will get you a string like "2020-07-17" but not a comparable date. You need to parse the date to compare it.

Try this instead:

```
 var givenDate = Date.parse(document.myForm.inputDate.value);
```

```js
function getDate() {
  var givenDate = Date.parse(document.myForm.inputDate.value);
  if (!givenDate.isNaN) {
  
   // set hours, minutes, seconds, milisecconds to zero for a comparison
   // on date only
    givenDate = new Date(givenDate).setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var todaysDate = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); 

    if (givenDate >= todaysDate) {
      result.innerHTML = 'Great! You\'re starting on a future date or today!';
      result.style.color = 'green';
    } else {
      result.innerHTML = "Please choose a future date.";
      result.style.color = 'red';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="date" id="inputDate" name="inputDate" onchange="getDate()">
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: "2020-07-17" will be parsed as UTC, `setHours(0,0,0,0,)` shifts it to the start of the local day, which will be the previous day for those wth a negative timezone offset. E.g. currently New Your is UTC-5, so "2020-07-17" becomes 2020-07-16 19:00 local. Setting that to 0 hours shifts to 2020-07-16 00:00. So for a New Yorker, entering 2020-07-17 will be treated as if they'd entered 2020-07-16.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getDate() {
    var givenDate = Date.parse(document.myForm.inputDate.value);
  var todaysDate = new Date();
  if (givenDate >= todaysDate) {
    result.innerHTML = 'Great! You\'re starting on ' + givenDate;
    result.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "Please choose a future date.";
    result.style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="date" id="inputDate" name="inputDate" onchange="getDate()">
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Use Date.parse

```
var givenDate = Date.parse(document.myForm.inputDate.value);
```